# All devices stopped working

Tags: drivers

I have a problem with my Loki. Yesterday everything was fine, but after rebooting it up due to system updates, I noticed that everything stopped working. I mean things like, wifi, bluetooth, card reader, fn+volume up/down, fn+screen brightens etc. It's as if the system lost the drivers for everything, or it doesn't detect anything. Any helpful tips? I'm running latest Loki on a HP Elitebook 8460p.